# Vue3+TS+Electron app cannot run normally after being packaged

Tags: electron, vuejs3, electron-builder

I'm using Vue3+Vite+TS+Electron to build a desktop application, everything works fine when running in the development environment on my computer, but after packaging it into an exe program, there is an error at runtime.Click the program icon, the window can be opened normally, but many things cannot be displayed, and an error occurs.Image link here:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Nfh9A658z9rEsqH49

The approximate code is as follows:

```
<div class="left">
          <Transition>
            <div class="bgimage"> </div>
          </Transition>
</div>
<div class="right">
          <Transition>
            <div class="form">
              <LoginForm />
            </div>
          </Transition>
</div>
```

The main error messages are：

1.When a custom component (<LoginForm />) exists in the right box: the style of class bgimage is lost.

2.When a custom component (<LoginForm />) exists in <Transition>, an error will be reported when running after packaging. The error message is: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'subTree')

3.When a custom component (<LoginForm />) exists outside the <Transition>, or when the <Transition> is placed inside a <LoginForm /> component, problem 2 is resolved, but I get a new error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property ' currentRoute' of 'e.useRouter(...)' as it is undefined, this error should be reported in <LoginForm />.

After solving a problem, new problems often appear, and there is no problem with the development environment on my computer, so I feel that it is not a problem with the program code, but a problem caused by packaging. The code for packaging the configuration file is as follows:

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "vue-element-plus-admin",
  "version": "1.4.1",
  "description": "test product",
  "author": "Archer",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/electron/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "i": "pnpm install",
    "dev": "vite --mode base",
    "ts:check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "build:pro": "vite build --mode pro",
    "build:gitee": "vite build --mode gitee",
    "build:dev": "vite build --mode dev && electron-builder",
    "build:test": "npm run ts:check && vite build --mode test",
    "serve:pro": "vite preview --mode pro",
    "serve:dev": "vite preview --mode dev",
    "serve:test": "vite preview --mode test",
    "npm:check": "npx npm-check-updates",
    "clean": "npx rimraf node_modules",
    "clean:cache": "npx rimraf node_modules/.cache",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.ts,.scss,.vue ./src",
    "lint:format": "prettier --write --loglevel warn \"src/**/*.{js,ts,json,tsx,css,less,vue,html,md}\"",
    "lint:style": "stylelint --fix \"**/*.{vue,less,postcss,css,scss}\" --cache --cache-location node_modules/.cache/stylelint/",
    "lint:lint-staged": "lint-staged -c ./.husky/lintstagedrc.js",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "p": "plop",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && cross-env IS_DEV=true electron .",
    "electron:dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm dev\" \"npm electron\"",
    "electron:builder": "electron-builder",
    "build:for:electron": "cross-env ELECTRON=true vite build",
    "app:build": "npm run build:for:electron && npm run electron:builder"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.8",
    "@iconify/iconify": "^2.2.1",
    "@vueuse/core": "^8.4.2",
    "@wangeditor/editor": "^5.0.1",
    "@wangeditor/editor-for-vue": "^5.1.10",
    "@zxcvbn-ts/core": "^2.0.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "echarts": "^5.3.2",
    "echarts-wordcloud": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-store": "^8.1.0",
    "element-plus": "2.2.0",
    "intro.js": "^5.1.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "lowdb": "^3.0.0",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "mockjs": "^1.1.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.14",
    "pinia-plugin-persist": "^1.0.0",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "vue": "3.2.33",
    "vue-i18n": "9.1.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.15",
    "vue-types": "^4.1.1",
    "web-storage-cache": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^16.2.4",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.2.4",
    "@iconify/json": "^2.1.43",
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^3.4.0",
    "@purge-icons/generated": "^0.8.1",
    "@types/intro.js": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/qrcode": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.23.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^1.3.10",
    "@vueuse/electron": "^8.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^19.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.3",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-define-config": "^1.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "lint-staged": "^12.4.1",
    "plop": "^3.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "postcss-html": "^1.4.1",
    "postcss-less": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-pxtorem": "^6.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.73.0",
    "stylelint": "^14.8.2",
    "stylelint-config-html": "^1.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^7.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^25.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "unplugin-vue-define-options": "^0.6.1",
    "vite": "2.9.9",
    "vite-plugin-electron": "^0.4.9",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.6.0",
    "vite-plugin-html": "^3.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-mock": "^2.9.6",
    "vite-plugin-purge-icons": "^0.8.1",
    "vite-plugin-style-import": "^1.4.1",
    "vite-plugin-svg-icons": "^2.0.1",
    "vite-plugin-windicss": "^1.8.4",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.34.13",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1",
    "windicss": "^3.5.3",
    "windicss-analysis": "^0.3.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 14.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.client.desktop",
    "productName": "Client",
    "asar": true,
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2022 Client",
    "directories": {
      "output": "release/${version}"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist"
    ],
    "mac": {
      "artifactName": "${productName}_${version}.${ext}",
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "artifactName": "${productName}_${version}.${ext}",
       "icon":"public/logo.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": false
    },
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
      }
    ],
    "releaseInfo": {
      "releaseNotes": "Nothing"
    }
  }
}
```

vite.config.ts:

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { loadEnv } from 'vite'
import type { UserConfig, ConfigEnv } from 'vite'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import WindiCSS from 'vite-plugin-windicss'
import VueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import EslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint'
import VueI18n from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n'
import styleImport, { ElementPlusResolve } from 'vite-plugin-style-import'
import { createSvgIconsPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-svg-icons'
import PurgeIcons from 'vite-plugin-purge-icons'
import { viteMockServe } from 'vite-plugin-mock'
import DefineOptions from 'unplugin-vue-define-options/vite'
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html'

import electron from "vite-plugin-electron";
import electronRenderer from "vite-plugin-electron/renderer";
import polyfillExports from "vite-plugin-electron/polyfill-exports";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
const root = process.cwd()

function pathResolve(dir: string) {
  return resolve(root, '.', dir)
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({ command, mode }: ConfigEnv): UserConfig => {
  let env 
  const isBuild = command === 'build'
  if (!isBuild) {
    env = loadEnv((process.argv[3] === '--mode' ? process.argv[4] : process.argv[3]), root)
  } else {
    env = loadEnv(mode, root)
  }
  return {
    base: env.VITE_BASE_PATH,
    plugins: [
      Vue(),
      VueJsx(),
      WindiCSS(),
      styleImport({
        resolves: [ElementPlusResolve()],
        libs: [{
          libraryName: 'element-plus',
          esModule: true,
          resolveStyle: (name) => {
            return `element-plus/es/components/${name.substring(3)}/style/css`
          }
        }]
      }),    
      EslintPlugin({
        cache: false,
        include: ['src/**/*.vue', 'src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.tsx'] 
      }),
      VueI18n({
        runtimeOnly: true,
        compositionOnly: true,
        include: [resolve(__dirname, 'src/locales/**')]
      }),
      createSvgIconsPlugin({
        iconDirs: [pathResolve('src/assets/svgs')],
        symbolId: 'icon-[dir]-[name]',
        svgoOptions: true
      }),
      PurgeIcons(),
      viteMockServe({
        ignore: /^\_/,
        mockPath: 'mock',
        localEnabled: !isBuild,
        prodEnabled: isBuild,
        injectCode: `
          import { setupProdMockServer } from '../mock/_createProductionServer'

          setupProdMockServer()
          `
      }),
      DefineOptions(),
      createHtmlPlugin({
        inject: {
          data: {
            title: env.VITE_APP_TITLE,
            injectScript: `<script src="./inject.js"></script>`,
          }
        }
      }),
      electron({
      main: {
        entry: "./electron/index.ts", 
      },
      preload: {
        input: require('path').join(__dirname, "./electron/preload.ts"), 
      },
    }),
    electronRenderer(),
    polyfillExports(),
    ],
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        less: {
          additionalData: '@import "./src/styles/variables.module.less";',
          javascriptEnabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json', '.less', '.css'],
      alias: [
        {
          find: 'vue-i18n',
          replacement: 'vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.cjs.js'
        },
        {
          find: /\@\//,
          replacement: `${pathResolve('src')}/`
        }
      ]
    },
    build: {
      minify: 'terser',
      outDir: env.VITE_OUT_DIR || 'dist',
      sourcemap: env.VITE_SOURCEMAP === 'true' ? 'inline' : false,
      brotliSize: false,
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_debugger: env.VITE_DROP_DEBUGGER === 'true',
          drop_console: env.VITE_DROP_CONSOLE === 'true'
        }
      },
      emptyOutDir: false, 
    },
    server: {
      port: 3000,
      proxy: {
        // '/api': {
        //   target: [process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_LOCAL],
        //   changeOrigin: true,
        //   rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
        // }
      },
      hmr: {
        overlay: false
      },
      host: '0.0.0.0'
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: [
        'vue',
        'vue-router',
        'vue-types',
        'element-plus/es/locale/lang/zh-cn',
        'element-plus/es/locale/lang/en',
        '@iconify/iconify',
        '@vueuse/core',
        'axios',
        'qs',
        'echarts',
        'echarts-wordcloud',
        'intro.js',
        'qrcode',
        '@wangeditor/editor',
        '@wangeditor/editor-for-vue'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

We tried modifying the config file, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try packaging with `asar: false` and see if that resolves the issues. If yes then you may just need to add exceptions for some files to not be included in the asar archive in order to work properly, using `asar.unpack`.

Comment: When packaging, I changed the configuration asar: false  , but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @keymap probably meant `ssr: false` here (so use it as an SPA-only app) and not `asar` (typo).

Comment: @subliuda sry I don't know enough about vue/vite to help further. But it seems like there is some conflicting mix of minified & unminified assets getting loaded in the packaged version. Try skipping minification altogether or at least include sourcemaps to help debug.

Comment: @keymap What is currently determined is that as long as the routing link to other pages or components in the App.Vue, running is blank and reported an error after packing. The routing mode has been set to the hash mode.We found another project and tested it,the hash mode was running normally,the history mode was running an error, but our project is already in the hash mode and it cannot run normally.